# map2 error "arguments imply differing number of rows"

Tags: r

I was trying to fit a step function to a dataframe and determine how many cut points produce the lowest mse. And I kept having the same error message:

`Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 149, 1332`

My codes and the dummy dataframe go as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library{rsample)
library(broom)
library(rcfss)

set.seed(666)
df <- tibble(egalit_scale = runif(1481, 1, 35), income06 = runif(1481, 1, 25))
training_df <- vfold_cv(df, 10)
mse_df <- function(splits, cc){
  model <- glm(egalit_scale ~ cut(income06, cc),
              data = analysis(splits))
  model_mse <- augment(model, newdata = assessment(splits)) %>%
    mse(truth = egalit_scale, estimate = round(.fitted))
  model_mse$.estimate
}

tidyr::expand(training_df, id, cc = 2:15) %>%
  left_join(training_df) %>%
  mutate(mse = map2(splits, cc, mse_df))
```

The error happens at the step with `map2`. I tried running each of the 10 folds CV with a specific number of cut points, say 6. It turned out 9 out of the 10 folds worked with the function, but one didn't. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Is the package `rcfss`on CRAN

Comment: With `map2` you are looping over each row of the dataset i.e. every value of 'cc' with each lisst element of 'splits'. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: If I take the first row from the `expand/join` output `mse_df(out$splits[[1]],  out$cc[1])#
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 149, 1332
> mse_df(out$splits[[1]],  out$cc)#
Error in cut.default(income06, cc) : 'breaks' are not unique`

Comment: The error is coming from `augment(model, newdata = assessment(splits))` because `augment(model)` returns 1332 rows while the `assesssment(ssplits)` is only 149 row

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention it. `rcfss` can be installed with this: `remotes::install_github("uc-cfss/rcfss")`

Comment: And yes, I wanted to loop over every value of `cc` with each element in the list of `splits`. I thought `tidyr::expand` already generated every possible match between `cc` and `splits`. How can I fix this?

Comment: I posted a solution.  Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming from the

```
augment(model, newdata = assessment(splits))
```

because in the previous step

```
model <- glm(egalit_scale ~ cut(income06, cc),
          data = analysis(splits))
```

we do the `analysis` on the 'splits' instead of the `assessment` and this results in getting different number of rows, e.g.

```
out <- tidyr::expand(training_df, id, cc = 2:15) %>%
         left_join(training_df)

tmp <- out$splits[[1]]



analysis(tmp)
# A tibble: 1,332 x 2
#   egalit_scale income06
#          <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1        27.3      9.69
# 2         7.71     8.48
# 3        34.3     21.3 
# 4         7.85    15.8 
# 5        13.3     24.6 
# 6        26.2      8.67
# 7        34.3      4.78
# 8        17.9     16.8 
# 9         1.45    21.2 
#10         9.84    15.7 
# … with 1,322 more rows

assessment(tmp)
# A tibble: 149 x 2
#   egalit_scale income06
#          <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1        28.6     14.8 
# 2        17.8      2.47
# 3         5.03    24.3 
# 4        31.5      5.79
# 5        18.4     18.0 
# 6         4.05     8.06
# 7         2.28     8.16
# 8        28.6     16.8 
# 9        21.1      7.03
#10         3.67    14.2 
# … with 139 more rows
```

---

So, if we change the model statement with `assessment`

```
mse_df <- function(splits, cc){
  model <- glm(egalit_scale ~ cut(income06, cc),
              data = assessment(splits))
  model_mse <- augment(model, newdata = assessment(splits)) %>%
    mse(truth = egalit_scale, estimate = round(.fitted))
  model_mse$.estimate
}



library(yardstick)
out1 <- tidyr::expand(training_df, id, cc = 2:15) %>%
   left_join(training_df) %>%
   mutate(mse = map2_dbl(splits, cc, mse_df))
out1
# A tibble: 140 x 4
#   id        cc splits               mse
#   <chr>  <int> <named list>       <dbl>
# 1 Fold01     2 <split [1.3K/149]>  94.9
# 2 Fold01     3 <split [1.3K/149]>  94.6
# 3 Fold01     4 <split [1.3K/149]>  93.8
# 4 Fold01     5 <split [1.3K/149]>  94.5
# 5 Fold01     6 <split [1.3K/149]>  94.0
# 6 Fold01     7 <split [1.3K/149]>  92.0
# 7 Fold01     8 <split [1.3K/149]>  88.9
# 8 Fold01     9 <split [1.3K/149]>  91.2
# 9 Fold01    10 <split [1.3K/149]>  92.8
#10 Fold01    11 <split [1.3K/149]>  86.0
# … with 130 more rows
```

Comment: It works with `assessment`. Thank you so much! Can I ask a dumb question, though? What's the difference between `analysis` and `assessment`?

Comment: @EricAtani their doc is not clear.  I think the `assessment` is out-of-bag sample